# Unable to locate companion shared library

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, eclipse-rcp, macos-sierra

I work on a product which is built upon Eclipse RCP and has a lot of plugins associated with it. The product build is exported as a .zip file for mac. However after extracting the zip file using the default archive utility in mac and then trying to run the product, it results in a dialog box with the message "Unable to locate companion shared library". This issue started only after updating the mac to Sierra; it worked completely fine for El Capitan.

I have tried several things as suggested by different posts like

1) checking the paths in the .ini files

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
```

These paths are perfectly fine and respective startup jar and launcher folder exists on the paths specified.

2) Using a different extractor 
I used Keka extractor for mac and unzipped the build using it and surprisingly the product runs. I looked into the directory structure of the extracted build by the archive utility and keka. I noticed that there are few things missing in the build extracted by archive utility like some directories in configuration and p2 folder. I don't know whats causing it.

Since many of the product users simply use default archive utility in mac, is it possible to fix this issue somehow without letting the users download an additional extractor like keka?

Comment: Instead of posting this as a question maybe you'd rather email Apple about it if you suspect it is a bug in the Archive Utility. Given the application is closed source (to my knowledge). In your email I would include the output of the `zipinfo` command applied to your zipfile.

Answer (score 6):

I found the same problem with Talend in Sierra (also an app built on eclipse). The following command line seemed to fix the problem:
`xattr -c TOS_DI-macosx-cocoa.app` or generically
`xattr -c NameOfYourApp.app`